# Working with canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am able to draw a signature on my canvas. Now after that I want to save this signature as an image which can be used later.

I am unable to implement an `onClicklistener` on this canvas. Also I am unclear as to how this signature can be stored as an image. Please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(...);
Canvas can = new Canvas(bmp);
```

When you change your canvas, bitmap bmp will change too. Canvas is only raference to Bitmap canvas, and you have no need to save canvas. Save only Bitmap (bmp).

Comment: But how do i save bitmap to an Sd-card ?

Comment: I think you neend to use compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)

Comment: This method will write bitmap to outputStream. After that write this output stream to file on sd card.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location - see that

Answer (score 0):

To save the canvas drawing as an image, you need to convert it to a data url using the toDataURL method.  Once you have the data url, you can use it to set the source of an image element so the user can right click and download the image.:

```
// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

// set canvasImg image src to dataURL
// so it can be saved as an image
document.getElementById("canvasImg").src = dataURL;
```

Reference: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

Comment: but android doesn't quite support `toDataURL` :(