# Android Saving created bitmap to directory on sd card

Tags: android, image, save

I created a bitmap and now i want to save that bitmap to a directory somewhere. Can anyone show me how this is done. Thanks

```
FileInputStream in;
          BufferedInputStream buf;
           try {
                  in = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/dcim/Camera/2010-11-16_18-57-18_989.jpg");
                  buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                  Bitmap _bitmapPreScale = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
                  int oldWidth = _bitmapPreScale.getWidth();
                  int oldHeight = _bitmapPreScale.getHeight();
                  int newWidth = 2592; 
                  int newHeight = 1936;

                  float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / oldWidth;
                  float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / oldHeight;

                  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
               // resize the bit map
                  matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                  Bitmap _bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(_bitmapPreScale, 0, 0,  oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);
```

(I want to save _bitmapScaled to a folder on my SD card)

Comment: `newWidth = 2592` didn't it throws out of memory exception?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar it wouldn't if he just saves it to disk and doesn't use it in an imageview

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Hi You can write data to bytes and then create a file in sdcard folder with whatever name and extension you want and then write the bytes to that file. 
This will save bitmap to sdcard.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

//you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "test.jpg");
f.createNewFile();
//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

// remember close de FileOutput
fo.close();
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also try this.

```java
File file = new File(strDirectoy,imgname);
OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

Comment: I like this better because you don't have to mess with a byte array

Comment: @Andro Selva Is `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` really needed ? Since without it, the code works.

Comment: Hi. I am getting Unresolved reference on `bitmap`. What should I replace `bitmap` with?

Answer (score 4):

`_bitmapScaled.compress()` should do the trick. Check out the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)

Answer (score 4):

just change the extension to **.bmp**.

Do this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);

//you can create a new file name "test.BMP" in sdcard folder.
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "test.bmp")
```

It'll sound that I'm just fooling around, but try it once and it'll get saved in `BMP` format. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an update with a little more consideration for OOM and various other leaks.

Assumes you have a directory intended as the destination and a name String already defined.

```
    File destination = new File(directory.getPath() + File.separatorChar + filename);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();

        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass bitmap to the saveImage Method, It will save your bitmap in the name of a saveBitmap, inside created test folder.

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap data) {
                    File createFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"test");
                    if(!createFolder.exists())
                    createFolder.mkdir();
                    File saveImage = new File(createFolder,"saveBitmap.jpg");
                    try {
                        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveImage);
                        data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

and use this:

```
  saveImage(bitmap);
```