# how to take screenshot programmatically and save it on gallery?

Tags: android, sdk

i would to know what is the code to take a screenshot of the current screen (after a press of a button) and save it on a gallery because I don't have a device with sd cards. So i would to save in the default gallery. thank you

Comment: It's not possible unless your device is rooted.

Comment: try this one.....
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762643/android-take-screen-shot-programatically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762643/android-take-screen-shot-programatically

Answer (score 11):

```
  Bitmap bitmap;
  View v1 = findViewById(R.id.rlid);// get ur root view id
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

This should do the trick.

For saving

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
  File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "test.jpg")
  f.createNewFile();
  FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
  fo.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
  fo.close();
```

Comment: did u give the above answer a try??

Comment: Works fine, good answer. Don't forget to add permissions or it wont work: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 5):

```
    View v1 = L1.getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshots);
    image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

For complete source code go through the below blog

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-taking-screen-shots-through-code.html

For storing the Bitmap to see the below link

[Android Saving created bitmap to directory on sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263375/android-saving-created-bitmap-to-directory-on-sd-card)

Answer (score 1):

This will save to the gallery. The code also sets an image path.. that is useful with Intent.SEND_ACTION and email Intents.

```
String imagePath = null;
Bitmap imageBitmap = screenShot(mAnyView);
if (imageBitmap != null) {
    imagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imageBitmap, "title", null);
}


public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I know this is a few months old, but it sort of worked ... except ... it captured the contents of the view but NOT the subviews.  How do you get a bitmap of everything that is displayed on top of the view (aka, the entire screen)?

Answer (score 0):

As `323go` commented, this isn't possible unless your device is rooted, really.

But if it is, it might be a good job for [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) or if you're using an emulator.