# How to save a created bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, onclick, save, fileoutputstream

I want to save a created bitmap after a button clicked
How can I do that? and if possible to a specific location

Here are my codes:

```
quoteimage.requestLayout();
        if (quoteimage.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
            quoteimage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                // we check which build version we are using
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        quoteimage.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        quoteimage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }

                    viewToBitmap(quoteimage); ///this one creates the bitmap
                }
            });
        }




        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ///Here I want to save the bitmap
            }
        });
```

Comment: @NoMoreHelloWorld "Did you look"***** and yes I looked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call save() in onClick():

```
protected void save(){
 FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
  out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
  bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
// PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
 try {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to save your bitmap, also pass the file name and location as U like

```
 private createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName,String location) {

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+location);

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/"+location+"/");
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/"+location+"/"), fileName+".jpg");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    File externalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"your/location/"+fileName+".jpg");
    externaluri = Uri.parse(externalFile.getPath());
    Log.d("externaluri", externaluri.toString());

}
```

Example

```
createDirectoryAndSaveFile(yourbitmap, "your_image_name" ,"your/location");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Android Saving created bitmap to directory on sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263375/android-saving-created-bitmap-to-directory-on-sd-card)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

//you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "test.jpg")
f.createNewFile();
//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

// remember close de FileOutput
fo.close();
```