# Adding a bitmap to the drawable resources

Tags: android, android-resources

How can I add a `Bitmap` taken from the web (in the app i mean!) to the drawable resources? So i can access the `Bitmap` using `R.drawable.bitmapName`...

Comment: just move it into the drawable folder and eclipse should automatically generate the coresponding class entries in R.drawable......

Comment: I want to do it programmatically! The app starts and download the image from the web. I've done thiss step, but now how can i save it to R.drawable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't modify that folder once your app is installed. In that case, you must copy the bitmap to a file and access it from there. Take a look at this other question:

[Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location)

Comment: I just wanted the bitmap to be in R.drawable so i could get its id as an int. Is there another way to get the id?

Comment: No, there's no way to do so "programmatically".

Answer (score 1):

The resources are compiled at the apk building time, so you cannot change it in runtime. If you want to have some identifier you can consider creating a shared preference where you can put in relation the downloaded image file with some id. But it will take some effort from you to implement the functionality.