# How to get ROI of an image in Android

Tags: android

I have an image file (.jpg) which contains image like Face. From my application i want to capture that particular Face part and copy that part into a new bitmap file. I have a rectangular co-ordinates of that Face part, so how do i capture only Face part from the image file and copy that into a bitmap file??

Could any body help me to get rid of this problem....

Answer (score 2):

[Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) will do the creation. For save, read this: [Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location)

Comment: That is way easier than what I suggested. You should do that.

Comment: Thanks Xandy and Michiel for the information.. How do i get the x and y positions from the rectangle coordinates??

Comment: What's the type of object you hold the coordinates?

Comment: The type of object is Rect. I can able to get left, top, right, bottom from this object. and i dont know how to get x and y coordinates from the Rect object??

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
bitmap1.getPixel(x,y)
```

on the source image and using

```
bitmap2.setPixel(x,y,color)
```

on the destination image.

There is also a respective

```
bitmap1.getPixels( pixelArray, offset, stride, x, y, width, height)
```

which is undoubtedly faster.