# can you tell how to bring the image in image view

Tags: java, android

I am using camera in my application.Once i click the button to capture an image i need to get the same image in the image view which is placed right side of the preview immediately.Please tell me the code

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0):

you can find the answer in this question here is the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789554/capturing-image-using-camera-in-android) look at the first answer