# Getting the file path from a picture in ImageView

Tags: android, image, camera

Alright I am making an Android app, and using the CAPTURE_PIC_REQUEST to take a picture and store it as a preview on the screen in an imageviewer. I wanted to know how to get the Uri and actually path because I am planning on taking that information, saving it and accessing it later. So I can't figure how to get the Uri or path name from that picture I just took. Here is the code from my activity that is handling

```
package com.CS480;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AddEx extends Activity {
  static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337; 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);

    Button camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picButton);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);               
        }               
    });

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.returnedPic);  
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);  
    }  
}

}
```

So how from that image that I am getting back on the app do I get the file location

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, you can do something like this:

```
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

public class AddEx extends Activity {
  static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337; 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);

    Button camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picButton);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = 
                    new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    mImageCaptureUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);               
        }               
    });

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.returnedPic);  
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);  

        String pathToImage = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();

        // pathToImage is a path you need. 

        // If image file is not in there, 
        //  you can save it yourself manually with this code:
        File file = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut); // You can choose any format you want
    }  
}
```

From Android documentation about android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT:

> The name of the Intent-extra used to indicate a content resolver Uri
>   to be used to store the requested image or video.

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the URI of the image with

```
data.getExtras.get("URI");
```

but this might not work.   What you can do is simply save the Bitmap yourself. See this question for a guide on how to do that: [Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location)

Answer (score 1):

When you take your image, you must store it somewhere to get the location of the image.

To do this, you can store to the MediaStore:

```
String result = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "", "");

imageFileUri = Uri.parse(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this get image file path form Bitmap

```
public void uploadBitmap(Context mContext, Bitmap bitmap) {

    String imagePath = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added DESC");
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
            imagePath = uri.toString();
            Log.d("pathatka", uri.toString());
            break;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

The android documentation has an [example of defining a file URI for saving the output when you setup the Intent for your image capture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image).