# How to get the image name of the ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have an imageview in android . I want to get the name of the image which is set in the in the imageview. How can I do that ?

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.img);
//String name = findImageName(v);
if( name.equals(a))
{
   //do something
} 
else{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I think it's duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824579/get-the-filename-that-your-imageview-loaded-its-image-from

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this first of all you need to set a tag for your ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageview1" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg1"
    android:tag="bg1"/>
```

Now get the image name currently set on your ImageView by doing the following,

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.img);
String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(v.getTag());
```

and this should return the image tag name which is **"bg1"**.

Now compare the tag names or use it for further process

```
if( backgroundImageName.equals(bg1))
{
   //do something
} 
else{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: How you are setting the image into the ImageView?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the name ussing tag.

```
imageView.setTag("any name")
```

And retrieve the value using

```
String imageNameName = (String) imageView.getTag();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    String imageName = img.getContentDescription();
```

Comment: what do you mean by **image name** ? is the file name of the image? or the description you gave in xml as content description?

Comment: name of the image which is set in to the imageview through the xml file

Comment: can I know how did you set the name of the imageview in xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn´t you use something like this?

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.img);
if(R.id.someId == v.getId())
{
   //do something
} 
else{
   //do something
}
```

It´s easier than use resources' names.