# Android - ImageButton.getBackgroundResource?

Tags: java, android, object, imagebutton

i have matrix of image button, i want to know which one was clicked by their image background.
how i get the image button BackgroundResource?

like:

```
    switch (image.getBackgroundResource()) {
       case R.mipmap.blueflower
          image.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.cardback1);
          break;
       case R.mipmap.cardback1:
          image.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.blueflower);
          break;
       }
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't know about that, but you can set `android:tag` on each of the buttons and differentiate them by tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651209/how-to-get-the-image-name-of-the-imageview-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggling through `setTag` and `getTag` is one way to do it, probably the simplest.

There are a few ways to directly compare an image...

Can you get drawable? `image.getDrawable()`, then `img1.equals(img2)`, (you might need a `getConstantState()` in there)

Bitmap? `bmp1.sameAs(bmp2)` or pixel by pixel [Comparing Bitmap images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120439/comparing-bitmap-images-in-android/7696320#7696320)

Comment: thanks @TML, i used set tag and get tag, but still it was more helpful if Android had ImageButton.getBackgroundResource