# why I save the bitmap ( BitmapFactory.decodeFile's output) into a file is bigger than The original image file?

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, filesize, bitmapfactory

i  resize a Bitmapfile using opencv (android-jni) and save the out bitmap to a file named /mnt/sdcard/org.jpg

then use

```
resultBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/org.jpg");
```

to get the bitmap and re-save this resultBitmap to the file /mnt/sdcard/result.jpg

then  the org.jpg size is 100k  and the result.jpg size is about 300k

why?

my resize method use opencv in jni like this:

```
int FUN_ENTRY JNICALL Java_com_funlib_imagefilter_ImageUtily_nativeResizeBitmap(    
                                                                                JNIEnv* env, jobject obj , jstring srcPath , jstring destPath,  int w , int h , int quality)
{
    char* srcPath1 = jstringTostring(env , srcPath);
    IplImage *src = cvLoadImage(srcPath1,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
    if(srcPath1!=NULL)
    {
        free(srcPath1);
        srcPath1 = NULL;
    }
    if(src==NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    CvSize sz;
    double rate1 = ((double) src->width) / (double) w + 0.1; 
    double rate2 = ((double) src->height) / (double) h + 0.1; 

    double rate = rate1 > rate2 ? rate1 : rate2; 
    sz.width = (int) (((double) src->width) / rate); 
    sz.height = (int) (((double) src->height) / rate); 
    IplImage *desc = cvCreateImage(sz,src->depth,src->nChannels);
    if(desc==NULL)
    {
        cvReleaseImage(&src);
        return -1;
    }
    cvResize(src,desc,CV_INTER_CUBIC);
    if(desc==NULL)
    {
        cvReleaseImage(&src);
        return -1;
    }
    char* destPath1 = jstringTostring(env , destPath);

    int p[3];
    p[0] = CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
    p[1] = quality;
    p[2] = 0;

    cvSaveImage(destPath1 , desc , p);
    cvReleaseImage(&src);
    cvReleaseImage(&desc);
    if(destPath1!=NULL)
    {
        free(destPath1);
        destPath1 = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and my main is

```
File f = new File(filePath);
    String tmpDestPath = f.getParent();
    if(!tmpDestPath.endsWith(File.separator))
        tmpDestPath += File.separator;
    tmpDestPath += "org.jpg";
    int ret = nativeResizeBitmap(filePath, tmpDestPath, width, height , quality);         //get the org.jpg file
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if(ret == 0){
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmpDestPath);
    }

    try {
        ImageUtily.saveBitmapToFile("result", bmp);  //get the result.jpg file
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my saveBitmapToFile is

```
    public static void saveBitmapToFile(String fileName, Bitmap bmp) throws IOException
{
    File f = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/TEMP/" + fileName + ".jpg");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
    try {
        fOut.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: try dialing down your `quality` parameter in  `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);` from `100` to something lower. 100 = max quality which isn't going to give you small JPEG images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know OpenCV / Android-JNI, so I can just try to give you a hint.

I suppose the function `saveBitmapToFile` does what it says on the tin: save a bitmap (as in [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)) as it is. You would need to compress your `bmp` first, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location) could point you in the right direction.

As to why the new file is bigger: if you really want to know (and are not just interested in how to fix it), fire up a Hex editor of your choice and take a look at the [file header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_.28bitmap_information_header.29). Bitmap uses various bit depths and compressions which may have been changed during the process.

Comment: You may save a ARGB_8888 Bitmap, which is default and at least recommended I think (check Bitmap.Config). If your origin bmp is an RGB_565, it is half size because ARGB_8888 = 32 bit, RGB_565 = 16 bit.