# file.exists() returns false but the image uri exists

Tags: java, android, file, uri

I've spent hours trying to figure out my problems but I just can't seem to figure out the solution.

I'm trying to delete an image that was saved when I was trying to get it's uri. The image was put in the internal storage.
My code is:

```
Uri imageUri = getImageUri(this, selectedImage);
File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
if (!file.exists()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "nope");
else{
    file.delete();
}
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context Context, Bitmap image) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(Context.getContentResolver(), image, "Title", null);
    Log.i(TAG, path);

    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

However, file.exists() returns false despite the fact that I have just made the image uri. Why is this so?

**Update**

Thanks to Shinil M S I have found the solution to my problem. However I have one more issue in that whenever I delete the photo, the image is replaced with this other empty image. I have attached the picture as I'm not sure exactly what it is. How do I get rid of it completely so that the image doesn't appear at all? [Image mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtrYk.png)

**Update 2**

I have gotten everything to work as intended.

My code is:

```
public static void deleteUri(Context context, Uri uri){

    long mediaId = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
    Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri itemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri, mediaId);

    context.getContentResolver().delete(itemUri, null, null);
}
```

I used this person's solution: [Deleting files via a 'ContentResolver' as opposed to deleting them via 'file.delete()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925196/deleting-files-via-a-contentresolver-as-opposed-to-deleting-them-via-file-del)

Comment: try getting absolute path, this may be giving a path content://

Comment: what is the path of `selectedImage?`

Comment: What is your image path ? and what you are getting in `File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883311/3983054

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Uri imageUri = getImageUri(this, selectedImage);
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

File file = new File(filePath);
if (!file.exists()) 
  Log.i(TAG, "nope");
else 
  file.delete();
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I have one more minor problem which I will update my original post with.

Comment: How are you loading the image to your imageView? Are you using any libraries?

Comment: I use the imageView.setBitmap() method.