# Android, How to store image in internal storage?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to store bitmap image on internal storage (not external storage). I have written this code but it seems something has problem. Because when i download image from DDMS, I can't open it.

```
public String writeFileToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap outputImage) {

        String fileName = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";

        try {
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            osw.write(outputImage.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Image stored at: " + fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.toString()); 
            fileName = null;
        } 

        return fileName;
    }
```

Comment: You're attempting to write out your `Bitmap` as a `String`, using `outputImage.toString()`.  I don't even know what that would get you, but not a valid image, I think.  [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

outputImage.toString() is not the image :) the contant you put on the file is not the binary data, but some string!

A way to do it is this:

```
public String writeFileToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap outputImage) {
    String fileName = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";

    final FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
}
```

I coded directly into the browser, it is possible to have some syntax errors, but the code should work.

Comment: Thanks dear Zelter, But unfortunately when I use this code new red line comes below "openFileOutput" and I can't run the application.

Comment: It says there is not a method in class and ask me to create it.

Comment: call `context.openFileOutput`

Comment: Thanks dear Zelter, it works fine. Just, can you tell me how to get image address? because after saving image i should save its path to database for later reference. Thanks

Comment: I found the way. :)  String fileName = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";
  File cacheDir = context.getFilesDir();
  String path = cacheDir.getPath() + fileName;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use .toString() instead of compressing the Bitmap into a FileOutputStream:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
outputImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

The internal storage can be retrieved via the Context, too.

```
File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, But it doesn't work as well. It throws "FileNotFoundException". Complete message from logcat is: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /1342996573233.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)