# Android: How to save the filtered image as a file?

Tags: android, filter, bitmap, imageview

all
   I want to make a filter just like what instagram's. I use an ImageView with colorFilter to accomplish the effect, but I don't know how to save the filtered image as a file. If I savethe bitmap directly, the original bitmap was stored without filter effect. If I store the imageview's pixels, its size is not as the same as the bitmap. And I dont want to calculate pixel by pixel for a new bitmap for effect reason. I was blocked on this problem for days.Would anybody help me ?
   Thanks.
BR
QiuPing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution now. 
I used a Canvas on the original bitmap, and paint with ColorMatrixColorFilter. 
Different ColorMatrixColorFilter take different use. Changing brightness, changing saturation, changing contrast. Make  combinations, then filters were created.

Comment: How you saved the bitmap because when i try to get bitmap all my ColorFilters are removed...

Comment: this is something written 5 years ago. sorry I could not find it now.

Comment: Thanks I have figured that out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be of help to you. Check out the Saving Internal and Saving External sections.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You're going to want to get your image into a bitmap, like this:

[Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location)