# Convert colour image to grayscale image using Android OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, grayscale

I need to convert a colour image to grayscale using Android OpenCV. And I need to show the grayscale image in ImageView. My sample image in drawable folder give me simple code.

I have already installed and configured SDK, NDK, OpenCV, and OpenCVManager in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make a colormatrixlter with saturation(0), then set it to your imageview

```
    yourImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_name);
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
    yourImageView.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Comment: thanks ur answer. can u give me sample code. i dont know how to fill filter value

Comment: How to put load my picture in drawable folder to this code segment.

Comment: Use this to set image to the imageview yourImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_name);
and use the above code to set saturation to your imageview.

Comment: Yea it worked.but i have no previlage to i have only 1 reputation. if u dont mind can u tell me how to save that grayscale image.

Comment: Use bitmap factory and decode the image, save it to a file.

Comment: can u please give code. i try this but not work. i want save grayscale image under drwable folder.


BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri ,string )), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

Comment: look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location