# I want to save bitmap to gallery

Tags: java, android, bitmap

So I have this application and I take a screenshot of edited image and save it to bitmap. Like here:

```
 imv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 bm = imv.getDrawingCache();
```

And now I want to save this bitmap to device. How should I go about doing this? Is somehow converting said bitmap to table of bytes a good idea?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/q/649154/1064310

Comment: Hi there! I [edit]ed your question to remove the "please help" at the end of it - it's not necessary here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a `FileOutputStream` with `Bitmap.compress` for that:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(filename + ".png"));
```