# How to set image for imageview and linear layout from Drawable path in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I was successful to load image to linear layout and image from local path as below code

```
    ImageView imagePerson=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPerson);
    LinearLayout layoutID=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutID);
    imagePerson.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
    layoutID.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layout1);
```

However, I need to save the path of these image in to file. Thus, I cannot use above code to load image to imageview and linearlayout. Instead of this, I want to find the way to load image from path. Could you help me to solve it in android. This is my code to get path

```
        String pathPerson="drawable://" + R.drawable.imgPerson;
        String pathID="drawable://" + R.drawable.layoutID;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can save the drawable id in integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ways are:

```
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
```

Other ways :

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.segf4ult.test/" + R.drawable.icon);
Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.segf4ult.test/drawable/icon");

String path = path.toString();
String path = otherPath .toString();
```

You can Create a Drawable  from a String path like this:

```
String pathGet = "/path/to/file/myFile.jpg"; 
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathGet);
```

Thanks

Comment: No.  i save it successful. I want to load to image/linear layout

Answer (score 1):

Use int type to save the drawable id.

Eg.

```
int drawablePerson = R.drawable.imgPerson;

int drawableId = R.drawable.layoutID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add like this in path..

```
  String pathPerson="wright your package name:drawable/" + R.drawable.imgPerson;
```

I think this is work for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to save the data to a file using this method [Save Bitmap to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)

then you can use 
`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName);`
refer to [Android Developer BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String))