# How to convert Drawable into int and vice versa in Android

Tags: android, drawable, android-sharedpreferences

I want to convert **Drawable** into **int** and then vice versa.Basically I want to save **Arraylist** object into **sharedPrefrence**. For that purpose I have Implement **Gson** to Srtring convertion Method. If I use here **Drawable** instead of **int** then Gson String convertion take alot of time. so I want to use int instead of Drawable.

```
 private List<AppInfo> apps = null;

   public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

   apps.get(position).setIcon(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(apps.get(position).getIcon()));
```

Where AppInfo here is

```
    public AppInfo(String appname, String pname, String versionName, int versionCode, int icon, int color) {
    this.appname = appname;
    this.pname = pname;
    this.versionName = versionName;
    this.versionCode = versionCode;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.color = color;
}
```

Here is source of Converting ArrayList of Custom object into String so that i can save it to SharedPrefrence.

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            apps.get(number).setColor(picker.getColor());
            String JsonAppsdata = gson.toJson(apps);
            System.out.println("Storing="+JsonAppsdata);
            utility.StoreData(getApplicationContext(), JsonAppsdata);
```

Comment: Do you have all icons in your resources? Or are you downloading them from the server?

Comment: And how do you populate List<AppInfo> apps?

Comment: At first time I populate it from the res/drawable then after this if some one (user) want to change that icon with some one in system app icon then i need to get system install application icon. In short, some time I need to get from res/drawable and some times i need to get icons from install application's icon from the system, by this mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(apps.get(position).getPname())

Comment: So what stops you from keeping this mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon() int into your AppInfo?

Comment: I can't use Drawable in AppInfo, I used here int instead of Drawable because of a case that i have discussed above. Now I need to convert this into int.

Comment: mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon() this returns Drawable I need to convert it into int so that my AppInfo  not affect.

Comment: You can call `getApplicationInfo()` method(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) instead. It returns `ApplicationInfo`, which contains icon's int. And then convert it to drawable (as menioned in my answer :-) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99124/discussion-between-tarikhelian-and-konstantin-loginov).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Int -> Drawable:**

`Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(42, getTheme());`

**Drawable -> Int:**

(I assume, that you're populating `List<AppInfo> apps` with app's whose icons are already in `res/drawable` folder of your app)

Once you set your `R.drawable.app1` to `ImageView`, you can also give it a `tag` to identify the resource in the `ImageView` later:

```
    ImageView appIcon1ImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.app_icon_1);
    appIcon1ImageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.app1));
    appIcon1ImageView.setTag(R.drawable.app1);

    ......
    // Once you need to identify which resource is in ImageView
    int drawableId = Integer.parseInt(appIcon1ImageView.getTag().toString());
```

If your icons are coming from server - the only way is [to store them to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location) and then re-load them. (or, better, rely on the already existing image-caching solutions like [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/))

**UPD:**
There's no direct way of converting `Drawable` into `int`, but in this particular case, it's possible to get the `int`, instead of `Drawable` from `PackageManager`:

```
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(apps.get(position).getPname(),1);
int icon= applicationInfo.icon;
```

Comment: There is problem that I am facing is resource id not found exception while                                                     ApplicationInfo applicationInfo=mContext.getPackageManager(). getApplicationInfo(apps.get(position).getPname(),1);
                   int icon= applicationInfo.icon;
                   apps.get(position).setIcon(applicationInfo.icon);       //while getting back int->Drawable
`Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(apps.get(i).getIcon()); 
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(imageArray[i]);
imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);`

Comment: How can I do the same for a drawableLeft? I'm using drawableLeft with a TextView and retrieving it's values using getCompoundDrawables method. So how can I convert that to an int.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we can fetch app icon and set it for an imageview.

```
                   applicationInfo=mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(apps.get(position).getPname(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                   int icon= applicationInfo.icon;
                   Rsources resources=mContext.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(applicationInfo);

                 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        holder.itemIcon.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(icon,null));
                    }else
                    {
                         holder.itemIcon.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(icon));

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99124/discussion-between-tarikhelian-and-konstantin-loginov) by @KonstantinLoginov, but instead of using:

`val drawable = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo)`,

I passed in the packageName:

`val drawable = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName)` which is String and can easily be passed around.