# "File upload onError,Incorrect content type" in quickblox

Tags: java, android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am trying to upload images in quickblox, i already did it once, but I receiving now this message of error.

My file for example is this one: "/data/user/0/dinidiniz.tradersmtg/app_Traders MTG Images/Sat Apr 30 20:58:36 GMT-03:00 2016.png". I tested, it exists and works just fine to get the bitmap.

When i upload using:

```
QBContent.uploadFileTask(imageFile, fileIsPublic, null, new QBEntityCallback<QBFile>()
```

I receive this error:

```
04-30 20:58:36.979 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err: com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: File upload onError,Incorrect content type
04-30 20:58:36.979 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at com.quickblox.content.task.TaskEntityUploadFile.performTask(TaskEntityUploadFile.java:74)
04-30 20:58:36.979 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at com.quickblox.content.QBContent.uploadFileTask(QBContent.java:560)
04-30 20:58:36.979 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at dinidiniz.tradersmtg.activities.ProfileEditActivity.changeAvatar(ProfileEditActivity.java:183)
04-30 20:58:36.979 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at dinidiniz.tradersmtg.activities.ProfileEditActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileEditActivity.java:166)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6442)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3716)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
04-30 20:58:36.980 5634-5634/dinidiniz.tradersmtg W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add "OutPutStream.flush();" after creating the image at the file that it started to have a content. I forgot this line.

Comment: where you added these line

Comment: I saved the bitmap, but forgot to flush the OutPutStream. In case you want to see how to save correctly a bitmap, you can see here:


[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)

Comment: This is not working for me. Can you please share example code for quickblox file upload