# The best way get Bitmap from android IntentService to get

Tags: android, web, client, intentservice

I'm developing Web-client on Android. I use IntentService for http-request. As a result, the object are formed by IntentService which have not only the primitive types, but also, for example, Bitmap object field. Tell me, please, best way to pass the object in the Activity, or some another class.
I try used ResultReceiver, but callback method get only Bundle-object:

> void onReceiveResult (int resultCode, Bundle resultData)

Bundle-object is only suitable for storing simple types. Translate large Bitmap-object as byte array is not recommended.

The second path, that to pack the object in the Parcel and set in Intent. Then catch it using BroadcastReceiver. How about sending large object in Broadcast message?

Perhaps you can just save the image and pass through the OutputStream way? Or just save it as a static variable somewhere? I'm not an expert of Android, the main thing I want to get fast app. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: have you tried storing it on a disk and then reading it in your Activity?

Comment: I'm finding best way. However, I may write as File in android file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bundle-object is only suitable for storing simple types. Translate large Bitmap-object as byte array is not recommended.

Yes, you should never transfer large data via `Intent`. It's not about data type, it's about size.

> The second path, that to pack the object in the Parcel and set in Intent. Then catch it using BroadcastReceiver. How about sending large object in Broadcast message?

It's same thing, sending a message still requires `Intent` which has limitations.

> Or just save it as a static variable somewhere?

This will work but this is a bad architecture. If you do this you will always have to think about that static field and be sure at all times that you are not keeping a static reference to the `Bitmap` you no longer need. I strongly don't recommend this.

Instead, you can store your `Bitmap` object to disk and then read it in your `Activity`. Here is an example: [Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)