# How to send an attached photo taken from camera using JavaMail?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I'm having some trouble with sending a image using JavaMail API. I get the image from camera but, I don´t know how to send this with attach in message. This is how I developed until now, below.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


import static android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy;
import static android.os.StrictMode.setThreadPolicy;

public class DenunciaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText campoNome;
    private EditText campoCPF;
    private EditText campoEmail;
    private EditText campoTelefone;
    private EditText campoNomeDoEstabelecimento;
    private EditText campoBairroDoEstabelecimento;
    private EditText campoPontoDeReferencia;
    private EditText campoDescricaoDenuncia;
    private Spinner campoSexo;
    private Spinner campoMotivo;
    private Button botaoSubmeter;
    private ImageView logoBack;
    private String contaEmail;
    private String senha;
    private Session session;
    private ImageButton primeiroBotao;
    private ImageButton segundoBotao;
    private ImageButton terceiroBotao;

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_denuncia);

        //localização dos itens na tela
        campoNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNomeID);
        campoCPF =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoCPFID);
        campoEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoEmailID);
        campoTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoTelefoneID);
        campoNomeDoEstabelecimento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNomeDoEstabelecimentoID);
        campoBairroDoEstabelecimento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoBairroEstabelecimentoID);
        campoPontoDeReferencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoPontoDeReferenciaID);
        campoDescricaoDenuncia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoDescricaoDenunciaID);
        campoSexo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.campoSexoID);
        campoMotivo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.campoMotivoID);
        botaoSubmeter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmeterID);
        logoBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageGoBackID);
        primeiroBotao = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraPrimeiraID);
        segundoBotao = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraSegundaID);
        terceiroBotao = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraTerceiraID);

        //Verificar se existe camera
        if(!hasCamera()){
            primeiroBotao.setEnabled(false);
            segundoBotao.setEnabled(false);
            terceiroBotao.setEnabled(false);
        }

        //inicializaçao ds variaveis senha e email
        contaEmail = "*******@******.com.br";
        senha = "*************";

        //ArrayAdapter campo sexo sexo
        ArrayAdapter sexo = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.array_sexo,
                R.layout.spinner_layout);
        sexo.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_new);
        campoSexo.setAdapter(sexo);

        //ArrayAdapter campo motivo
        ArrayAdapter motivo = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.string_motivos,
                R.layout.spinner_layout);
        motivo.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_new);
        campoMotivo.setAdapter(motivo);

        //botão logoBack
        logoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(DenunciaActivity.this, "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //botão primeira camera
        primeiroBotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //Toast.makeText(DenunciaActivity.this, "Primeira câmera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //botao segunda camera
        segundoBotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(DenunciaActivity.this, "Segunda câmera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //botao terceira camera
        terceiroBotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(DenunciaActivity.this, "Terceira câmera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Botão submeter
        botaoSubmeter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ThreadPolicy policy = new ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                setThreadPolicy(policy);
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.**********.**.**.br");
                //properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
                //properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
                //properties.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable", "true\"");//novaLinha

                try {

                    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                        @Override
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(contaEmail, senha);
                        }
                    });

                    if (session != null){
                        String campos = "Dados do consumidor" + "<br/>" + "Nome: " + campoNome.getText().toString() + "<br/>" + "CPF: " + campoCPF.getText().toString() +
                                "<br/>" + "E-mail: " + campoEmail.getText().toString() + "<br/>" + "Telefone: " + campoTelefone.getText().toString() + "<br/>"
                                + "Sexo: " + campoSexo.getSelectedItem().toString() + "<br/>" + "<br/>" + "Dados do fornecedor" + "<br/>" + "Nome do estabelecimento: " +
                                campoNomeDoEstabelecimento.getText().toString() + "<br/>" + "Bairro estabelecimento: " + campoBairroDoEstabelecimento.getText().toString()
                                + "<br/>" + "Ponto de referencia: " + campoPontoDeReferencia.getText().toString() + "<br/>" + "Motivo: " + campoMotivo.getSelectedItem().toString()
                                + "<br/>" + "Descrição da denuncia: " + "<br/>" + campoDescricaoDenuncia.getText().toString();
                        //Toast.makeText(DenunciaActivity.this, "antes do try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(contaEmail));
                        message.setSubject("Formulário denuncia App");
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("*****@*****.****.*****.br"));
                        message.setContent(campos,"text/html; charset=utf-8");
                        Transport.send(message);
                        Toast.makeText(DenunciaActivity.this, "Email enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    //se tiver uma camera, ele retorna true
    private boolean hasCamera(){
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment your question. There's a good tutorial on how you can put an inline image using javamail on tutorialspoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_inlineimage_in_email.htm

You'll need to save your picture to a file in order to do that so take your bitmap and save to file (here you can find how to do it if you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/673014/7194993 )

Comment: I take a look of some examples, and I tried use some of examples. and I can save it picture now. But, I need to retrieve a url and pass it like string to a FileDataSource(DataSource source = new FileDataSource(here);) handling it. So, at lest it was what I understud.
So, I still have a problem..
:/

Comment: once you have saved your bitmap you have the save path. Use that path to create a FileDataSource instance