# Is it possible to transfer image to 3 different activities?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new at programming. I am implementing a project which consists of 3 java classes (FirstActivity, SecondActivity and ResultActivity). The image taken is at FirstActivity. I need to transfer the image to the SecondActivity and then from SecondActivity to ResultActivity. Take note that FirstActivity and the ResultActivity only has imageview to display with. Please help me. Can someone suggests a sample code for me to be guided. Any advice will be much appreciated :)

First Activity:

```
  ImageView imgTaken = findViewById(R.id.imgTaken);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgTaken.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(ProcessImage.this, Match.class);
            i.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap);
            startActivity(i);
```

Second Activity:

```
final Bitmap bitmap  = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(Match.this, Request.class);
            i.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap);
            startActivity(i);
```

Result Activity:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Bitmap bitmap  = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Please help me.

Comment: are you using android? also include code that you have tried.

Comment: I'd try by using intent sir but sadly, it didn't work. @Karan Mer

Comment: post code that you have tried with your question

Comment: @KaranMer, I just posted the code sir. Please let me know if I've done something wrong.

Comment: store the image in file and pass its uri around activities. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Simplest answer would be make your Bitmap static like this: 
public static

Answer (score 2):

Send with `Intent` like this following:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);

byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

Intent i = new Intent(context,SecondClass.class);

i.putExtra("bitmap",ba);
```

Get the data from `Intent` like this:

```
byte [] ba1 =getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("bitmap");

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba1,0,ba1.length);
```

Comment: Hi sir @Rakesh Kumar, can this be applied to the succeeding activities? Like Second Activity to ResultActivity?

Comment: @student76, Yes you can do by using `setResult(11,i);`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, Simplest answer would be make your Bitmap static like this:

```
public static Bitmap bitmap = null;
bitmap = ((Bitmap) imgTaken.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

start next activity and then access that image like :

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(FirstActivity.bitmap);
```

Comment: Hi sir @Faisal, no image appear on my image view at Result Activity. Please help :(

Comment: are you taking image using camera?
and then storing it?

Comment: Yes sir. I have called the camera using Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: Ok, so after taking picture are you storing it in gallery or not?

Comment: After capturing it is automatically saved on the gallery sir.

Comment: can you post your whole First Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
final Bitmap bitmap  = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
```

Make this change

```
 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().get("Bitmap");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest will be

1. create a BaseActivity that extends all your first, second and result
   activity with BaseActivity.
2. Store the image bitmap in a variable that is declare in BaseActivity.
3. And from the BaseActivity you can have access to bitmap image from any of your Activity.

this one is the simplest way, but there are may other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Very big thanks sir. I will try to apply it and will inform you if something changes :)

Comment: It didn't work sir @Suryakant, an class cannot extends multiple classes. Pleas help.

Comment: @student76 have given another answer for the same post please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

@student76 I don't know How you were doing this, but ill explain it more..

1. create a base activity class
   ex: public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   }
   and crate doo all the works here
2. create your first activity
   ex ex: public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {
   }
   in this you will have you will process the image and store the image on a variable that is declare in the base activity
3. create your Second activity
   ex ex: public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity {
   }
   now directly access the variable that you declare in BaseActivity.
   now you have access to the image
4. create your Second activity
   ex ex: public class ThirdActivity extends BaseActivity {
   }
   Same as SecondActivity.
   in this way you can have access to the bitmap in all you activity.